# Pivoting with a condition present

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am working in **MySQL 5.7.35** and I have the following tables:

**Structure**

```
create table Table1 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(Id)
);

create table Table2 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    Table1_Id int not null,
    primary key(Id),
    foreign key(Table1_Id) references Table1(Id)  
);


create table Table3 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Type varchar(255) not null,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    Result varchar(255) not null,
    Table2_Id int not null,
    primary key(Id),
    foreign key(Table2_Id) references Table2(Id)
);
```

**Data**

Inside, I have the following data:

```
| Id  | Name       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | Computer A |

---

| Id  | Name       | Table1_Id |
| --- | ---------- | --------- |
| 1   | Test Run 1 | 1         |

---

| Id  | Type      | Name      | Result  | Table2_Id |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1   | Processor | MMX       | Pass    | 1         |
| 2   | Processor | SSE       | Pass    | 1         |
| 3   | Processor | SSE 2     | Pass    | 1         |
| 4   | Display   | Red       | Pass    | 1         |
| 5   | Display   | Green     | Pass    | 1         |
| 6   | Keyboard  | General   | Pass    | 1         |
| 7   | Keyboard  | Lights    | Skipped | 1         |
| 8   | Network   | Ethernet  | Pass    | 1         |
| 9   | Network   | Wireless  | Skipped | 1         |
| 10  | Network   | Bluetooth | Fail    | 1         |
```

**Desired Query**

I've had a change in requirements where now, each `Type` value ought to be turned into a column, with the value calculated with the following logic:

For any given value in `Type`:

- If **all** are passes, then the result is a `Pass`
- If **any** are fails, then the result is a `Fail`
- If any are Skipped (*providing the first two points are checked*), then the result is `Skipped`.

So for the current data, the output will be:

```
| table1_name | processor_test | display_test | keyboard_test | Network |
| ----------- | ---------------|--------------|---------------|---------|
| Computer A  | Pass           | Pass         | Skipped       | Fail    |
```

**Current Query**

I am struggling to do the conditional pivoting when the columns/values are in a child table two levels down. My current query is:

```
select t1.Name as 'table1_name'
-- pivoting columns
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
inner join Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id;
```

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GzGKnfwNaHvsKcaPzytyy/2) to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table to prioritize the results

```
create table Priority (
  Id int not null ,
  Result varchar(255) not null
);

insert into Priority(id, result)
values 
(1,'Fail'),
(2,'Skipped'),
(3,'Pass')

select grp.table1_name, grp.Type, p.Result
from (    
    select t1.Name as table1_name,
    t3.Type, min(p.id) mp
    from Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
    inner join Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
    inner join Priority p on p.Result = t3.Result
    group by t1.Name, t3.Type) grp
join Priority p on p.Id = grp.mp;
```

The result then can be pivoted as needed.

**EDIT**

You can also use CASE to encode/decode priorities

```
select table1_name, 
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN Type='Processor' 
            THEN Result
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'processor_test',
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN Type='Display' 
            THEN Result
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'display_test',
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN Type='Network' 
            THEN Result
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'network_test',
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN Type='Keyboard'
            THEN Result
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'keyboard_test' 
  from (    
    select t1.Name as table1_name,
        t3.Type, 
        case min(
            case t3.Result 
              when'Fail' then 1
              when'Skipped' then 2
              when'Pass' then 3
            end) 
          when 1 then 'Fail' 
          when 2 then 'Skipped'     
          when 3 then 'Pass'
        end Result
    from Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
    inner join Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
    group by t1.Name, t3.Type
    ) t
 group by table1_name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Serg, am I right that with [your approach above](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GzGKnfwNaHvsKcaPzytyy/3) things **aren't dynamic**? In other words, I would need to know all possible `Type` values beforehand?

Comment: Also, how would this look without the creation of a new table?

Comment: @J86 , yes, if you want  a varying number of pivoted columns you must use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can use CASE instead of the Priority table in the solution.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the case working @Serg. :(

Comment: @J86, added CASE version.